# How to use connection as standalone object with types?

Tags: node.js, typeorm

Not working code just to illustrate what I'm trying to achieve

Some connection file

```
import { ConnectionManager } from 'typeorm';

const c = new ConnectionManager();
// user ormconfig.conf file
export const connection = c.createAndConnect();
```

using in some model

```
@Entity()
@Table("annual_incomes")
export class AnnualIncome
{
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column({ length: 75 })
    variant: string;

    @Column("int")
    sort: number;

    @Column()
    is_active: boolean;
}
```

Later somewhere in the code, I want to get connection with all methods, something like:

```
import { connection } from 'someconnection';
import { AnnualIncome } from 'entities';

// some code here

api.get('/incomes', async(ctx) => {
    ctx.body = await connection.getRepository(AnnualIncome).find();
});
```

Usually, I'm getting an error from `tsc` that `.getRepository()` method was not found in `connection`. However if I do something like:

```
import { connection } from 'someconnection';
import { AnnualIncome } from 'entities';

// some code here

api.get('/incomes', async(ctx) => {
    ctx.body = await connection.then(async connection => {
       return await connection.getRepository(AnnualIncome).find();
    }
});
```

the above code works with definitions and `tsc` does not complain about not-existing methods.

I'd like to avoid an extra definition `connection.then()` and get plain `connection` with all methods defined in `<Connection>` type.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

just use `createConnection` method to create your connection when you bootstrap your application. Later you can access your connection from anywhere using `getConnection()` method:

```
import { AnnualIncome } from 'entities';
import { createConnection, getConnection } from 'typeorm';

// somewhere in your app, better where you bootstrap express and other things
createConnection(); // read config from ormconfig.json or pass them here

// some code here

api.get('/incomes', async(ctx) => {
    ctx.body = await getConnection().getRepository(AnnualIncome).find();
});
```

Also you can simply use `getRepository` method also avalible from anywhere:

```
import { AnnualIncome } from 'entities';
import { getRepository } from 'typeorm';

// some code here

api.get('/incomes', async (ctx) => {
    ctx.body = await getRepository(AnnualIncome).find();
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I want to notice that if use just `getRepository()` I have to set up connection name `await getRepository(AnnualIncome, 'default')`

Comment: actually you can omit connection name parameter because its by default is `default`. You should use only when your name a specific connection name

Comment: probably there is collision between definitions or versions `https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/src/index.ts#L259` because  your example does not work for me in version `0.0.8` In my npm package I does not have this line `https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/src/index.ts#L269`

Comment: Isn't it better/safer to open and close connection every time you use it (instead reusing same connection all the time)?

Comment: no, its not efficient because each time connection opening and closing takes too much time

Comment: I'm a bit confused (maybe I'm missing know-how about async/await): in my typeorm/index.d.ts (v.0.0.11) there is following definition (note that there is no promise): `export declare function getRepository<Entity>(entityClass: ObjectType<Entity>, connectionName: string): Repository<Entity>;
`. Has API changed?

Comment: right getRepository does not return promise. `find` method of it returns promise and we are await `find`, not `getRepository`.

Comment: @pleerock. How does `createConnection` work? where does the connection go? is it stored in memory?

Comment: getConnection is deprecated now, is there other option?