# Reuse global database pool / connection

Tags: node.js, typescript, typeorm

I'm using TypeORM and want to be able to use the db connection in any module.

How would i realize this? I was thinking about something like this

```js
let connection = require('./mydb');
let User = require('./models/User');
// do something
connection.getRepository(User);
```

and in `mydb.ts` it would look a little like this:

```js
require('typeorm');
export createConnection();
```

But this exports the promise. What is the optimal workflow? How would i reuse the typeorm connection in other modules?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeOrm - How to use connection as standalone object with types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42186674/typeorm-how-to-use-connection-as-standalone-object-with-types)

Comment: Sorry, this was a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42186674/typeorm-how-to-use-connection-as-standalone-object-with-types